# The disk drive for .boot is not ready yet or not present

Tags: 14.04, hyper-v

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on Hyper-V in Server 2012 R2 Standard cluster . When I failed this VM over to the other node it booted up to this error :

The disk drive for /boot is not ready yet or not present . Continue to wait , or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery .

I can press S to skip past the error and the system boots , but the error comes back if I reboot the VM . I also cannot run a proper backup of the VM as the backup software is complaining that the boot partition is empty .

Has anyone seen this before  ? Any suggestions on getting past it  ?

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that the `/boot` partition (typically `/dev/sda1`) has been non-fatally damaged.  The system is still able to read and boot the kernel from it, but then it can't detect the partition to mount it later during startup.

Apart from this the system runs OK, but `/boot` isn't mounted, so you won't be able to see the grub files or do things like updating the kernel.

You'll probably find an entry for `/boot` in your `/etc/fstab` file 
that tries to mount it by its block id:

```
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=cc1f7924-150b-412c-81c0-a8931eed57f0 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
```

If you run `blkid`, you should see normally see an entry like this for `/dev/sda1`, but it is probably missing:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="cc1f7924-150b-412c-81c0-a8931eed57f0" TYPE="ext2"
```

`file -s` is able to identify it though, and will probably show the correct ID, but that it's damaged somehow:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=cc1f7924-150b-412c-81c0-a8931eed57f0 (needs journal recovery)
```

Running fsck on it will hopefully fix the problem (although in a VM it's probably worth taking a checkpoint/snapshot first):

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Superblock needs_recovery flag is set, but no journal is present.
Clear<y>? yes
/dev/sda1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 301/62248 files (15.3% non-contiguous), 46683/248832 blocks
```

After this `file -s` should show a filesystem without problems, and you should be able to mount it again, or have it mount successfully on reboot.

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=cc1f7924-150b-412c-81c0-a8931eed57f0
```